# Error with open graph and websites

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, web, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to debug this url but I get error all the time. why?
http://summerburst.se/stockholm/

This is the error message I get:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An unknown error has occurred.",
      "type": "OAuthException"
   }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow; please take some time to read the [faq](http://stackoverflow.com/faq). If someone's answer has answered your question, please don't forget to click on the check mark next to their [answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/171243).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your website configurations, there may be some limitations to bots. You are blocking Facebook bots that have requests to your site.

[This link](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=http://summerburst.se/stockholm/) shows that how Facebook scraper sees your page.

You can also check detailed URL debug results on [Facebook Object Debugger page](http://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://summerburst.se/stockholm/)

Comment: I found the problem:

<IfModule mod_security2.c>
SecRuleEngine Off
</IfModule>